# POS Printer not available in Pos .NET

Tags: printing, opos, pos-for-.net

My Bixolon SRP-350II is not shown in the list of available devices given by

```
posExplorer.GetDevices();
```

All I see are Microsoft's simulated devices. The printer itself works, I can print on it and, using raw printing, send commands such as "cut". I've installed the OPOS driver for the printer, but nothing changed.

Is it necessary to do some further configuration? Is the order of installing POS.NET, the OPOS-driver and the Windows driver important?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, figured out the Printer had to be configured with PSPLauncher.exe and now it shows up. Still, I am not sure I understand where exactly the benefit of POS .NET lies. I want the customers to plug-in new printers and when using Raw Printing and EscPos-commands, this seems to be much easier.

Plug printer in, install windows driver, set to main printer and then cut-commands etc. are being send in the raw stream.

Comment: pls i need help printing with a SRP-275II printer, can you send me a sample steps/code which will help

Answer (score 0):

I can't say directly for printers, but where we get the benefits out of POS.NET is the standard code we wrote for the scanners, or MSRs or cash drawers.  All we have to do is install the driver, and configure the device in OPOS configuration (which is probably the step you were missing and resolved with the "PSPLauncher.exe") and we know that it's code-compatible and just works.

We have hundreds of terminals across the country (Australia) and they all use a variety of models and brands for the devices (within a range of tolerance) but because of POS.NET they're all supported.

Comment: pls i need help printing with a SRP-275II printer, can you send me a sample steps/code which will help